# How to reload an activity from a tab activity in android?

Tags: android, list, tabs, reload

I would like to reload my activity from custom tab.The activity mainly consist of a listview in it & how to load in it again.Any snippets or sample code will be helpful.I have tried all things corrsponding to Reloading an activity in Android,I would like to know regarding custom tab.Thanks.

```
 listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

  mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLAdapter(this);
  mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

  cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

  String[] from = new String[]{SQLAdapter.YMM,SQLAdapter.SS}
  int[] to = new int[]{R.id.ymm,R.id.ss};
  cursorAdapter =
   new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
  listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
  listContent.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);
  cursorAdapter.getCursor().requery(); 
  cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the data in the list and invalidate the list view by calling getListView().invalidateViews() the activity will automatically get updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added my code above does this work above where do I need to invalidate it.

Comment: call listContent.invalidateViews()